# Get specific date objects from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a an array called week:

```
[Mon, 08 Jun 2015, Tue, 09 Jun 2015, Wed, 10 Jun 2015, Thu, 11 Jun 2015, Fri, 12 Jun 2015, Sat, 13 Jun 2015, Sun, 14 Jun 2015]
```

I need to get a mon and fri from the array without using their index.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: This is not valid ruby array.

Comment: @mudasobwa I suspect that's the result of a valid array printed into irb.

Comment: what do you mean "get a monday/friday"? Do you mean get the date-like-object that is the thing right after the "Mon" entry?  Why do you need it to not use the index? (cos the easiest answer is to get the index of "Mon" then take the next one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby provides [`Date#monday?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-monday-3F) and [`Date#friday`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-friday-3F) methods to determine if a date matches the specific weekday.

Therefore, to find the monday in the array, assuming the array is made of `Date` instances

```
array.find(&:monday?)
```

if it's made of `Time` instances, then

```
array.find { |time| time.to_date.monday? }
```

If you want to get both monday and friday, simply use select

```
# for Date
array.select { |date| date.monday? || date.friday? }
# for Time
array.select { |time| date = time.to_date && (date.monday? || date.friday?) }
```

Comment: That was masterful and succinct. I knew there had to be a simple way.

Comment: Good answer. Note that there's a method [Date#to_date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-to_date), which returns `self`, meaning that your solutions for `Time` instances work for `Date` instances as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
week = [Mon, 08 Jun 2015, Tue, 09 Jun 2015, Wed, 10 Jun 2015, Thu, 11 Jun 2015, Fri, 12 Jun 2015, Sat, 13 Jun 2015, Sun, 14 Jun 2015]
```

Assuming those are `Date` objects in there, you can ask each if they are a certain weekday:

```
week.select { |d| d.monday? || d.friday? }
```